Support of OIDC backchannel logout using XML security config
I do not see any simple way to introduce the Spring Security backchannel logout in the current Spring Security Config XML configuration. The namespaces do not contain the java DSL OIDC backchannel logout possibilities. The documentation refers to reactive stack which was not yet required and it is not yet available in XML configuration.
Is there really no option to use OIDC backchannel logout easily using XML security configurations?
The https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd contains elements like security:oauth2-login with easy attribute configuration options however there are no attributes supporting the new DSL features for backchannel logout:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/login/logout.html#configure-provider-initiated-oidc-logout
[http].oidcLogout((logout) -> logout.backChannel(Customizer.withDefaults())
I am wondering if there is any simple way to support OIDC backchannel logout in a Spring/Spring Security application. In cases I would like to introduce the beans in XML manually, most probably the reactive stack needs to be somehow activated. Also the filter OidcBackChannelLogoutWebFilter is package private class without public setters so there is no way to inject any beans in the XML configuration. The same applies for OidcBackChannelServerLogoutHandler. It there any way to register OidcBackChannelLogoutWebFilter to ServerHttpSecurity (represented by <http> element)? Most probably for registering WebFilters is additional reactive stack configuration required.
Do you know about any way how to achieve that? I would like to avoid the the reactive stack if possible, but I am also open to workaround with the reactive stack.
Thank you in advance for your answers.
